# What is wrong with this Safari Blocker Regex?

Tags: swift, regex, safari, safari-extension

I am developing a Safari extension (https://github.com/bcye/Hello-Goodbye in Safari folder) and am trying to block chat widgets.

I tried to block (in Chrome extension syntax) `*://widget.intercom.io/*`

So I am trying to block http or https and any path on widget.intercom.io

I tried out these two Safari blocker regex (documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker):

`https?:\/\/widget\.intercom\.io\/(.*)`
`https?://widget\.intercom\.io/.`

Both don't work.

I tried debugging them on https://regex101.com/ and it tells me that the first one should work.

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/N3jUdW/1

Comment: Share you exact regex101 page, so we can see your test data and play with it for ourselves

Comment: @Alexander I edited the post with the link https://regex101.com/r/N3jUdW/1

Comment: I don't know what context these regexes are being used in, but I suspect one of the issues if that characters like `\/` are being interpreted like "escape sequence `/`", the way `\n` is interpreted as "escape sequence `\n`" (which represents new lines). Most likely, you'll need to double up your slashes, so that you have `\\/`. The first slash starts an escape sequence, the second "ends" it, and says "no no, I wanted a literal `/`", which is then making its way into the final regex, followed by the `/`.

Comment: Show the code, how these patterns are used in it. `\/` is ok, but it depends on the use case.